# Send a socket between applications c#

Tags: c#, sockets, pointers, transfer

I would like to know if there is a way where you have a .net app name appA where it receives a tcp socket connection and then according to some rules will send the socket connection to another
.net app named appB.
I know this violates alot of security and good practice,but would be interesting if it would be possible.

Comment: You mean like... AppA waiting on a given TCP port for an incoming connection, and - if established - opening a socket connection to another application AppB and sending the payload to it? Sure it's possible.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 3):

**Proxy**

One option is to make AppA a proxy. That is, it accepts the connections, and connects on behalf the client to AppB - and merely forwards the data.

**Socket Duplication**

The solution you are really looking for is [`Socket.DuplicateAndClose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.duplicateandclose.aspx) (make sure you read the documentation carefully). This allows you transfer the control of a socket between processes.

Typically you would:

- Start AppA, AppB and AppC.
- Use remoting to allow AppA to communicate with AppB and AppC.
- When a connection is made to AppA, determine who to send it to and:

  - Duplicate and close the socket in AppA.
  - Send the socket to the child process via remoting.
  - Open the socket in AppB using the `Socket(SocketInformation)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No need to forwarding the connection, it can be use to act as a **middle men**

1. You receive the first connection
2. Process some rules
3. All ok, connect to AppB and everything that get's from AppA, send to AppB
4. If Rules say "no", send an error to AppA