# Transferring sockets between processes?

Tags: c#, sockets, process, transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send a socket between applications c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359330/send-a-socket-between-applications-c-sharp)

Is it possible to somehow transfer connected sockets between processes?

What I have is a server, with connected sockets (TCP). Sometimes I need to restart the program, but while you're restarting, all the connections are broken, so all the connected users have to reconnect.

Is it possible to "transfer" these connections on to a different process, so I can restart the main program and then move the socket connections back to the main program? Something like "Host Migration" in Call Of Duty games.

Answer (score 2):

The [Socket.DuplicateAndClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.duplicateandclose.aspx) method converts a socket into a form you can pass to another process which can then open the socket.

Answer (score 0):

(CoD :) Funny ... what's your handle? We will play sometime)

Anyhow, not really ... unless you code your client to handle exceptions and reconnect as needed. Alternatively, you could have a load-balancing-router in front of your hosts. WCF Peer networking comes to mind.